# How to matched wordpress encrypted passowrd in nodejs?

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress, password-encryption

How do I do user authentication from wordpress database in nodejs?

I need to validate user password whose hash is created using `wp_hash_password` in wordpress link [wp_hash](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_hash_password/)

Now, I need to validate user password using nodejs. I have tried many nodejs modules but failed.

Comment: I think you will need to create a local API and make a call from your node app...

Comment: yes i can make a local API ,but it will take time.I just want to make sure can I verify it in node side?

Comment: You can do it but you'll have to use same hashing algorithm with same keys on both sides.. Can you post some code?

Comment: I have their php code but since i have no idea about php,but they are doing like  require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php';\
 $hasher = new PasswordHash( 8, true );\

Comment: this is the salt save in db like "$2a$08$r7Y1uBH2ku0nAO6.W6aHC.OHeOhJ.AKP.6sKJUunpzkj1wBbjnC7G"   for password = "testuser123"

Comment: This makes use of phpass library

Answer (score 0):

I've found two libraries that help you to implement phpass hash in node js.

phpass: https://www.npmjs.com/package/phpass

wordpress-hash-node: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordpress-hash-node

Comment: I have already tried both.But they give me a false result . :(

Comment: Can you check difference between hash generated by phpass vs hash generated by one of above libraries... This might be caused by different versions of bcrypt underneath... If first 6 characters are different then this can be solved

Comment: hash store in db for "testuser123" is "$2a$08$r7Y1uBH2ku0nAO6.W6aHC.OHeOhJ.AKP.6sKJUunpzkj1wBbjnC7G"   and by using phpass hash is generated is "$2a$08$4BlGY4Q69PCzYH3qS/BLNOGQzjgsFwrYhiauP7izT6r8.XBV0C.qy"

Comment: Matching actuall password with hash like :   var checked= passwordHash.checkPassword("testuser123",hashSaveindb);
                console.log("checked::: ",checked);